# Fedora to Fedora remote desktop does not work (connection closed error, even after setting everything up)

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, fedora

I'm trying to use remote desktop on my laptop (running Fedora) to my desktop (also running Fedora) on the same local network.

I configured Remote Desktop on my desktop via System -> Preferences -> Remote Desktop, verified that the port is open by nmap, and attempted to connect from my laptop via vinagre (also tried appending :5900 for the port, and using the ip address). In all cases, the connection fails with a popup that says "Connection closed\n Connection to host was closed."

EDIT: I am able to use vinagre from the desktop to remote desktop into itself, just not from one machine to the other. I tried vncviewer and a similar problem occurs (`unable connect to socket: No route to host (113)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the firewall settings on your desktop (the machine you're trying to connect to) have not been configured properly.  Use the Firewall Settings tool (System > Administration > Firewall) to ensure that you have TCP port 5900 open.  Start the tool, choose Other ports, and verify that TCP 5900 is in the list.  If it's not, add it, and try your process again.

(Also, the port worked from the desktop machine to itself because the loopback network device is already trusted by the default firewall configuration.)

Answer (score 0):

Open the ports for the VNC Server in the remote machine:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=vnc-server

sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=vnc-server
```